# Guzzle 6 is following redirects on local docker server, but not on production server

Tags: php-7, guzzle, guzzle6

I am using Guzzle 6 Http Client to scrape web pages and analyze them from SEO perspective, however interesting thing is, that Guzzle does not follow redirects at all, when being used in production, but code is exatly the same. Here is the snippet I am using to request page and track redirects.

```
    $onRedirect = function (RequestInterface $request, ResponseInterface $response, UriInterface $uri): void {
        $this->totalRedirects++;
    };

    $response = $this->httpClient->request('GET', $url, [
        'allow_redirects' => [
            'max'             => self::MAX_REDIRECTS,
            'referer'         => true,
            'track_redirects' => true,
            'on_redirect'     => $onRedirect
        ],
        'headers' => [
            'User-Agent' => self::USER_AGENT
        ],
        'http_errors' => true
    ]);

    $redirectUrls = $response->getHeader('X-Guzzle-Redirect-History');
    $redirectStatuses = $response->getHeader('X-Guzzle-Redirect-Status-History');
    foreach ($redirectUrls as $key => $redirectUrl) {
        $this->responses[] = new HttpResponse($redirectUrl, $redirectStatuses[$key]);
    }
    //Save last successful response
    $this->responses[] = new HttpResponse($url, $response->getStatusCode());
```

My redirect middleware is not triggered at all, using this in production and it returns only "307", while in docker I get "307" and "200". This have been tested using samaritans page - (https://www.samaritans.org/)

Both Production and docker are using PHP 7.2 and Guzzle 6

Comment: Hey! I'm having a similar issue. Did you manage to find a solution? Thanks.